# Android graphics: How does TransitionDrawable work?

Tags: android, animation, graphics, view, drawable

I read the documentation but I can't manage to make a transition occur. What's the flow of events supposed to be like? Who calls who?

Suppose I wanted to have an activity call init() to draw line a, and call go to make a 5 second transition to line b. What would I have to do to this code?

```
public class Fun extends View
{
    Drawable a;
    Drawable b;
    TransitionDrawable t;
    public Fun(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        a = new LineA();
        b = new LineB();
        Drawable ray[] =  {a,b};
        t = new TransitionDrawable( ray );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        t.draw(canvas);

    }

    public void init()
    {
        t.resetTransition();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        t.startTransition(5000);
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It doesn't work with View, the extended class must be an ImageView.